# Get a new Datatable by defactorate a column c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I get a `DataTable`  like below (first image),in the last column I have concatenate item(separate by ";") that I want to disassemble like the second image ,I have tried sevral ways that does not work ,if any one can help me .
Ps :I dont know the numbers of element in any cell of the last columns (the belows are just exemples):
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("produit", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("test1", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("test3", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("logistique", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("testAjout", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("testAjout1", typeof(string));
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "P1", 1, 3, "t3;t1;t2", "t4;t5;t6;tr", "T34;T25", "Rahima;T33;T55;T66" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "P2", 1, 4, "t9;t10;t55", "t2;t1;t3", "t34;t45", "Nadji" });

            DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.AsEnumerable())
            {
                string produit = row.Field<string>("produit");
                int test1 = row.Field<int>("test1");
                int test3 = row.Field<int>("test3");
                //int test4 = row.Field<int>("test4");
                string[] splitLogistique = row.Field<string>("logistique").Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
                string[] splitAmount = row.Field<string>("amount").Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
                string[] splitAjout = row.Field<string>("testAjout").Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
                string[] splitAjout1 = row.Field<string>("testAjout1").Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToArray();
                int[] Lengths = new int[4];
                Lengths[0] = splitAjout.Length;
                Lengths[1] = splitAjout1.Length;
                Lengths[2] = splitAmount.Length;
                Lengths[3] = splitLogistique.Length;
                Array.Sort(Lengths);
                Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                dic.Add("splitAjout", splitAjout.Length);
                dic.Add("splitAjout1", splitAjout1.Length);
                dic.Add("splitAmount", splitAmount.Length);
                dic.Add("splitLogistique", splitLogistique.Length);
                int maxLength = Math.Max(Math.Max(splitLogistique.Length, Math.Max(splitAmount.Length, splitAjout.Length)), splitAjout1.Length);

                for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
                {
                    if ((i < splitLogistique.Length) && (i < splitAmount.Length) && (i < splitAjout.Length) && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                    {
                        dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { produit, test1, test3, splitLogistique[i], splitAmount[i], splitAjout[i], splitAjout1[i] });
                    }
                    if ((i >= splitLogistique.Length && (i < splitAmount.Length) && (i < splitAjout.Length) && (i < splitAjout1.Length))

                      || (i >= splitLogistique.Length && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                      || (i >= splitLogistique.Length && (i < splitAjout.Length))
                      || (i >= splitLogistique.Length && (i < splitAmount.Length))
                      || (i >= splitLogistique.Length && (i < splitAjout.Length) && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                      || (i >= splitLogistique.Length && (i < splitAmount.Length) && (i < splitAjout.Length))
                      || (i >= splitLogistique.Length && (i < splitAmount.Length) && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                      || (i >= splitLogistique.Length))
                    {
                        //DataRow newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
                        //newRow.ItemArray = new object[] { produit, test1, test3 , splitAmount[i] , splitAjout[i] };
                        dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { produit, test1, test3, splitAmount[i], splitAjout[i], splitAjout1[i] });
                    }
                    if ((i >= splitAmount.Length && (i < splitLogistique.Length) && (i < splitAjout.Length) && (i < splitAjout1.Length))

                     || (i >= splitAmount.Length && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAmount.Length && (i < splitAjout.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAmount.Length && (i < splitLogistique.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAmount.Length && (i < splitAjout.Length) && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAmount.Length && (i < splitLogistique.Length) && (i < splitAjout.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAmount.Length && (i < splitLogistique.Length) && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAmount.Length))
                    {
                        //DataRow newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
                        dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { produit, test1, test3, splitAjout[i], splitLogistique[i], splitAjout1[i] });

                    }
                    if (i >= splitAjout1.Length && (i < splitAmount.Length) && (i < splitLogistique.Length) && (i < splitAjout.Length))


                    {   //DataRow newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
                        dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { produit, test1, test3, splitAmount[i], splitLogistique[i], splitAjout[i] });

                    }

                    if ((i >= splitAjout.Length && (i < splitAmount.Length) && (i < splitLogistique.Length) && (i < splitAjout.Length))

                     || (i >= splitAjout.Length && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAjout.Length && (i < splitLogistique.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAjout.Length && (i < splitAmount.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAjout.Length && (i < splitLogistique.Length) && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAjout.Length && (i < splitAmount.Length) && (i < splitLogistique.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAjout.Length && (i < splitAmount.Length) && (i < splitAjout1.Length))
                     || (i >= splitAjout.Length))
                    {
                        //DataRow newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
                        dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { produit, test1, test3, splitAmount[i], splitLogistique[i] });

                    }
                }
            }
            DataRow[] currentRows = dt2.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
            foreach (DataRow row in currentRows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt2.Columns)
                    Console.Write("\t{0}", row[column]);

                Console.WriteLine("\t" + row);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @lili1986, it seems that you're new around so please take some time to read the following topic on how to properly ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

PS: Post the code using proper format rather than posting screenshots.

Comment: Jimi yes this what I mean .

Comment: `I have tried sevral ways that does not work ,if any one can help me`  Why don't you share with us what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        const int HEADER_COLS = 3;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("produit", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("test1", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("test3", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("logistique", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("testAjout", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("testAjout1", typeof(string));
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "P1", 1, 3, "t3;t1;t2", "t4;t5;t6;tr", "T34;T25", "Rahima;T33;T55;T66" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "P2", 1, 4, "t9;t10;t55", "t2;t1;t3", "t34;t45", "Nadji" });

            DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();

            int cols = dt1.Columns.Count;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.AsEnumerable())
            {
                string produit = row.Field<string>("produit");
                int test1 = row.Field<int>("test1");
                int test3 = row.Field<int>("test3");

                //[column][number items spit by semicolon]
                string[][] splitData = row.ItemArray.Skip(HEADER_COLS).Select(x => ((string)x).Split(new char[] { ';'}).ToArray()).ToArray();

                int maxLength = splitData.Select(x => x.Length).Max();
                //add rows to data table using column with most semicolons
                for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
                    newRow.ItemArray = new object[] { produit, test1, test3 };

                    for(int col = HEADER_COLS; col < cols; col++)
                    {
                        if ( i < splitData[col - HEADER_COLS].Length)
                        {
                            newRow[col] = splitData[col - HEADER_COLS][i];
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to adapt the code to more then 4  but it  seems like it does not work? Ps:it work for three

Comment: I updated code.  They say : "'If the mountain will not come to Muhammad, then Muhammad must go to the mountain".  Meaning when the code becomes real messy you have to find another way of solving problem.